# What is the right way to compare as3 objects using hamcrest

Tags: actionscript-3, tdd, hamcrest, flexunit4

I'm trying to compare two objects to see if they are the same using hamcrest for flex-unit, but when the object has sub objects, it just throws an error:

```
Error: Expected: (An array containing <[object Object]>
but: an array containing <[object Object]> was <[object Object]>
```

I want it to do an assertThat(..., hasProperties(...)); on the sub object.

Is there a way to get that or should i create a custom matcher?

**EDIT**

An example of the object structure i want to test:

```
var expected:Object = {
    number:1.3,
    array:[{
        prop1:"val1", prop2:"val2"
    }]
    anObject:{
        propA:1, propB:2
    },
}

var objectUnderTest:Object = {
    number:1.3,
    array:[{
        prop1:"val1", prop2:"val2"
    }]
    anObject:{
        propA:1, propB:2
    },
}

assertThat("should be the same", objectUnderTest, hasProperties(expected));
```

since the expected and objectUnderTest have the same structure, the test should pass, but is returning the error:

```
Error: Expected: (An array containing <[object Object]>
but: an array containing <[object Object]> was <[object Object]>
```

Also, if there is a way to compare two JSON strings will be fine too.

**EDIT2**

This is my final version after djib help:

```
package com
{
    public function assertEqualsObjects(message:String, object1:Object, object2:Object):Boolean
    {
        // we have to run it both ways (1-2, 2-1)
        return (compare(object1, object2, message + ": object") && compare(object2, object1, message + ": extra"));
    }
}

import org.flexunit.asserts.fail;

function compare(object1:Object, object2:Object, parent:String):Boolean
{
    var count:int = 0;

    for (var s:String in object1)
    {
        count ++;
        if (!object2.hasOwnProperty(s))
        {
            fail(parent + "." + s + " expected: " + object1[s] + " but was: undefined");
            return false;
        }
        if (!compare(object1[s], object2[s], parent + "." + s))
        {
            fail(parent + "." + s + " expected: " + object1[s] + " but was: " + object2[s]);
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (count == 0 && object1 != object2) // if object has no properties, compare their actual values
    {
        fail(parent + " expected: " + object1 + " but was: " + object2);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: So you've got an array with objects and you want to verify what exactly? That the objects in the array have certain properties? Or that they are of a specific type? Or that they are specific instances?

Comment: Added an example of the code. Hope it clarify.

Comment: It still doesn't tell me what you want to test exactly. Do you want to verify that the object under test has those certain properties with those exact values, or do you want to verify that it simply has the 'anObject' and 'array' properties? I mean, how deep and strict does the verification need to go?

Comment: Added more details.
For my system, two objects are the same when they have the same properties with the same values. If a property is an object, this object should have the same properties.

The order of properties in the object and sub objects is not important, but the order of array should be the same.

You can think of it like comparing 2 JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

I've put this code together. Recursion is the key ^^

```
        // our two objects to compare ...
        var obj1 = {
            number:1.3,
            array:[{prop1:"val1", prop2:"val2"}],
            anObject:{propA:1, propB:2}
        };

        var obj2 = {
            number:1.3,
            array:[{prop1:"val1", prop2:"val2"}],
            anObject:{propA:1, propB:2}
        };

        trace(isSame(obj1, obj2)); // -> true


    function isSame(object1:Object, object2:Object):Boolean
    {
        // we have to run it both ways (1-2, 2-1)
        return (compare(object1, object2) && compare(object2, object1));
    }

    function compare(object1:Object, object2:Object):Boolean
    {
        var count:int = 0;

        for (var s:String in object1)
        {
            count ++;
            if (object2[s] == undefined)
                return false;
            if (!compare(object1[s], object2[s]))
                return false;
        }

        if (count == 0 && object1 != object2) // if object has no properties, compare their actual values
        return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working. Now i will add some traces, so i can know why the objects are not the same when they aren't.